# Send custom matrix and custom dimension to firebase analytics

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

How can we send custom metrics and custom dimension to Firebase analytic from iOS/Android plateforms?

Answer (score -1):

you can use 'User properties' as replacement for Custom Dimension

reference: https://growthbug.com/i-took-firebase-analytics-for-a-ride-heres-the-conclusion-8a148a2e6229