# How to create a custom dimension in Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I'm following [this Google tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/recommendation-system-tensorflow-apply-to-analytics-data) to implement a recommender system in to my application which is running with Firebase.

Where it states:

> Follow the Google Analytics documentation on custom dimensions to add
> an article ID dimension with hit-level scope to page tracking events.

However when I view my Google Analytics dashboard (not the firebase one) to add a custom dimension, I do not have the ability in my `Admin` tab. What is the recommended approach for adding custom dimension in a Firebase Analytics project?

[A previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131748/send-custom-matrix-and-custom-dimension-to-firebase-analytics) says to use `User Properties`, but my understanding is that we should not be using a User Property to add a custom dimension such as `articleID` since I need to specify its scope level.

Answer (score -1):

There aren't custom dimensions in new Property. The focus was specifically on custom parameters. They are the analogy with Custom Dimensions and Custom Metrics in Google Analytics Universal.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9478675?hl=en